# Space usage completely over the top, seems like a bug

Tags: cloud9-ide

This has just started happening and I have absolutely no idea why...

[image: Why could this be?]

Answer (score 0):

Strange I restarted and memory issues went away.. did a lot of things during the day, removed trash, deleted temp files etc... but didn't notice any effect until restarting via this (restart button at the bottom):

[image]

Still no idea what the hell happened, other than a lot of hours down the drain :(